# Query from multiple mySQL table at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I want to query some data, but the data is distributed into different tables based on the month (e.g.201301, 201302) the data was collected. I can try to query the tables by doing a union from all the tables I need. This is what I have so far..

```
select * from table_2013_01
where user_id = 39858
UNION ALL
select * from table_2013_02
where user_id = 39858
UNION ALL
.
.
.
select * from table_2014_01
where user_id= 39858
order by date asc
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way than this as I might want to retrieve data from 2010 year onwards? That would mean doing a union of all 36 tables in one go?
2. Will this cause performance issue as this is a live server and I cannot afford to do query for more than 2 minutes or it will send an alert to the DBA.

NOTE:
I only have read access from the DB. I cannot even create a temp table.

Comment: Look into table partitioning

Answer (score 1):

If you can create/put index on user_id (it seems you don't have any other parameter in where clause), then the retrieval will be faster, and then you can do

```
    select * from (
      select * from table_2013_01
      where user_id = 39858
      UNION ALL
      select * from table_2013_02
      where user_id = 39858
      UNION ALL
      .
      .
      .
      select * from table_2014_01
      where user_id= 39858
    ) t order by date asc;
```

If you have access to create procedures, then you need not to manually write these query, you can create dynamic SQL (String say *final_sql*) and can run it:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @final_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select *
from (select * from table_2013_01 
  union all 
  select * from table_2013_02 
  union all 
  select * from table_2013_03) a
where a.user_id = 12212;
```